# Doesn't calculate min and max grades in program. (c++) (fstream)

Tags: c++, max, average, min, ifstream

The point of this program is to open and read a text file, with student's academic code -> aem and the grade he/she has overall. Then, if the grade of a particular student is greater than 5, it will write his/her academic code on the text named successful, as well as the grade etc.
My problem is that it calculates the average of those 5 students grades correctly but it does not calculate the max and min grades. When I run the program, the window coming up, shows the correct average of the course, however max and min grades are always 0.
Can anyone help me? Probably I don't compare them in the right way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int arraySize = 5;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ifstream d;
    d.open("students.txt");
    ofstream b;
    b.open("succesful.txt");
    ofstream c;
    c.open("unsuccesful.txt");

    int aem;
    double a[arraySize];
    int min, max;
    double grades, average;
    grades = average = 0;
    min = max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        d >> aem >> a[i];
        grades = grades + a[i];
        average = grades / arraySize;

        if (a[i] >= 5) b << aem << " " << a[i] << endl;
        else c << aem << " " << a[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] = max)
            max = a[i];
        break;
        if (a[i] = min)
            min = a[i];
        break;
    }


    cout << "The average is:" << average;
    cout << "Maximum is:" << max;
    cout << "Minimum is:" << min;
    d.close(); c.close(); b.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code as text, not as image(s).

Comment: Your last loop does nothing except setting `a[1]` to `max` (`0`). Think about that, it will help you find the problem :)

Comment: Do I need to compare them in some way? Before, for function?

Comment: `=` is assignment. Equality comparison is `==`. (A decent compiler should warn you about this.)

Comment: Also, look at those `break`s and think carefully about what will happen. (Try to explain to yourself why you put them there.)

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
  if (i >= max)
   max == i; 
  if (i <= min)
   min == i;
 }

Comment: `==` is equality comparison. Assignment is `=`. (A decent compiler should warn you about this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

There's no need `argc` and `argv` to be here. It can be just `int main()`.

```
int min, max;
double grades, average;
grades = average = 0;
min = max = 0;
```

Assigning value after declaration is unnecessary and inefficient. Also, `0` is an integer, not a floating point. You can just initialize them: `int min = 0, max = 0;` `double grades = .0, average = .0;`

```
grades = grades + a[i];
```

Can be shortened to `grades += a[i];`

```
average = grades / arraySize;
```

This statement is inside a for-loop pointlessly. You can do this after the loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i < arraySize; i++) {
```

You forgot the zeroth element of `a`. `int i = 1;` must be replaced to `int i = 0;`

```
if (i >= max)
    max = i; 
if (i <= min)
    min = i;
```

You've mistaken `a[i]` for `i`. And if `a[i]` and `max` already compare equal, there is no need to assign `a[i]` to `max`. They can be just:

```
if (a[i] > max)
    max = a[i]; 
if (a[i] < min)
    min = a[i];
```

And,

```
system("pause");
```

`std::system` is dependent to the system environment and can have unexpected behavior. It should be replaced to:

```
std::cout << "Press enter key." << std::endl;
std::cin.get();
```